# Definition on white noise and C++

Tags: random, probability-density, noise-generator

i want to create white noise random numbers. I thought that white noise is gaussian distribution and i used the following code for number generation:

normal_distribution distribution

where mu is the median and sigma^2 the variance. But i've learnt that it isn't. What is the mathematically proper definition of white noise and how can it be defined in C++?

Comment: White noise is typically series of iid with 0 mean and some finite variance. So if you use gaussian white noise, set mu = 0 and variance to something and sample from normal_distribution. `But i've learnt that it isn't.` Could you please tell us what you've learned and show some code?

Comment: What thought was that white noise is another name for Gaussian distribution, so i modeled the white noise as a normal distribution with mu=0 and sigma=s, where s>0, therefire the generator was the following one:

normal_distribution<double>  white_noise(mu, sigma);

Each number is generated executing the following code:

rn=white_noise(rd)

Comment: mt19937 rd(random_device{}()) is used as generator

Comment: ok, that's one of the realizations of the white noise. There are less known realization with non-gaussian WN as well. Not clear what the problem is. Typically you have stochastic or deterministic process generating some data/time series. Then you add noise on top of it. Typical requirement is that WN is not shifting you mean, so mean of WH is required to be 0. Say, you start with exponential, and usually you do `X = exp_dist(rate); WN = norm_dist(0.0, stddev); return X + WN;`

Comment: Exponential above is just an example, use whatever underlying distribution you have to use

Comment: To demystify part of the question, you might find this link of interest, where it talks about white noise and its relationship with a Gaussian distribution http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3006/en/#toc4